# MVC3 Application cannot save files to directory no errors returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I'll give a brief summary first then add detail as I can.

I have an MVC3 application running on two servers.  I'll call them `box1` and `box2`.  Both servers are running the same OS, IIS versions, the same application loaded to from subversion.  `box1` works absolutely flawlessly.  It can perform uploads to the path specified in the web.config.  However, when I try to upload using `box2` **the directory is created** therefore my `Path.Combine` statement is working fine., but the actual file being uploaded is never created.

I don't get any error message, the upload just doesn't happen at all.  I thought it was due to the application setting for the path.  I thought maybe `box2` (in a different domain) does not have rights.  This is not true for two reasons

1. I do get an Access Denied error when I set the path to something that is inaccessible.
2. I even tried saving to `box2` directly on it's harddrive. Still only creates folder.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile, string id)
   {

           var dr405 = new DR405Service().GetDR405ById(new DR405DBContext(), DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
           var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
           System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
           if ((int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024 <= 15000)
           {

               uploadfile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName)));
               var file = new dr405files { TangiblePropertyId = DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId, FileName = uploadfile.FileName, UploadDate = DateTime.Now };
               //dr405.dr405files.Add(file); 
               //c.dr405s.Add(dr405);

               db.Entry(file).State = file.FileId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
               //db.Entry(dr405).State = EntityState.Modified;

               new DR405Service().Save(db);
               ViewData["UploadStatus"] = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.", uploadfile.FileName, (int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024);
           }
           else
           {
               ViewData["UploadStatus"] = String.Format("File exceeds 15MB upload limit.  Please reduce size and try again.", uploadfile.FileName);
           }


       return View();
   }
   ```

Here are a few of the hurdles I'm fighting

- `box2` is a production server, so I can't install remote debugger
- `box2` is hosted by another group and I have to tell them how to configure it.  They will not or are not capable of figuring out how to fix this.

### Update

While not the most elegant code this does work just fine.

[image]

### Update #2

I modified my Action to do a redirect to google since I can't actually run the debugger on the remote server yet.  What I discovered is on `box1` the redirect occurs.  On `box2` the redirect does not occur.  This makes me mostly certain that the controller action is never even getting called on `box2`.  How can this be?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        var dr405 = new DR405Service().GetDR405ById(new DR405DBContext(), DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
        var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath  + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
        if ((int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024 <= 15000)
```

### Update #3

Regardless of which of these versions of Path.Combine I use it does not change anything.  Please reread the question.  The `Action` doesn't even appear to get called on `box2`.
[image]

Comment: Does it write the success message even if it doesn't save the file?

Comment: No, It simply refreshes the page.  Nothing is written at all.

Comment: FYI. Your `Path.Combine` is flawed.

Comment: @DanielA.White How is it flawed could you elaborate?

Comment: I think Daniel is right -- shouldn't you have a comma instead of a + in there?

Comment: Can you get any access to the server at all?  Process Explorer (google for "download process explorer" is your best friend for finding answers to problems like this -- it will log every attempted file operation.  Use the filters to remove the noise, and 9 times out of 10, you'll find the failed write attempt (and usually its either a bad path, or a insufficient NTFS permissions)

Comment: @JMarsch good suggestion,  I meant access to configuring IIS.  Yes we did run process explorer. After the directory is created, nothing else happens.  No error for bad path, insufficient permissions, anything...

Comment: At this point I would run Fiddler and see what requests/responses are sent/received by the client browser. www.fiddlertool.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
```

to

```
var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath, DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
```

Comment: While you may be technically right. The application works correctly on `box1` without this change. This would impact all servers running my application.

Comment: Still, the code as it is is wrong. Calling `Path.Combine()` this way doesn't do anything.

Comment: No, you are wrong.  While it may be not the most elegant code it works.

Comment: @DougChamberlain: No, you're actually, really, wrong. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

Comment: @minitech my screen shot of my immediate window in my post proves otherwise.  Regardless this answer does not cover the question.

Comment: @DougChamberlain: So the 8 \\\\ don't bother you? That's the wrong way to use `Path.Combine` - we mean it!

Comment: @minitech please see my screenshot comparing the output.  Where are you drawing the conclusion that my way is "wrong" since they both generate exactly the same output?

Comment: Your way is wrong because all you are doing is calling Path.Combine with one parameter. It defeats the  purpose of using Path.Combine, namely automatic management of path separators. i.e. if you call Path.Combine with "c:\abc" and "file.txt" it will return "c:\abc\file.txt". Your method will return "c:\abcfile.txt". I agree though that this is probably not the root problem here.

Comment: I think I was drunk when I wrote this question. Thanks all.